# PrimeNG p-inputnumber unable to enter negative fractional numbers

Tags: angular, primeng

I need to capture negative decimals with PrimeNG's p-inputnumber component, but when entering the component, and minFractionDigits is > 0, entering a - jumps the cursor to the end of the display, so the number cannot be captured conventionally. 
. I can navigate back with the arrow keys, but it makes the usage painstaking and slow.

```
<p-inputNumber [(ngModel)]="modelNum" mode="decimal" locale="en-US"
[minFractionDigits]="2" [maxFractionDigits]="2"
(onFocus)="$event.target.select()" (ngModelChange)="calculateResults(row)">
</p-inputNumber>
```

Has anyone found a solution to this problem? 
**Environment:**
Angular version: 10.x
PrimeNG version: 10.0.3

Comment: Can you try (onInput) method instead of (ngModelChange)?

Comment: Thanks Alba, It turns out that the event is firing. The biggest issue is the behaviour of the component in this configuration. I spent a week upgrading the project to use A10 & Prime 10.  Its looks like a great component apart from this bug